# How to use Lazy Loading for DbQuery in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I am using Lazy Loading for EF Core 2.2.3 with proxies which works well with DbSets. Now I have to load data from a SQL View and am using DbQuery for this. When trying to load related data for the entity used in the query, I'm getting a DetachedLazyLoadingWarning:

> Error generated for warning
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DetachedLazyLoadingWarning:
>   An attempt was made to lazy-load navigation property 'ProjectStatus'
>   on detached entity of type 'ProjectProxy'. Lazy-loading is not
>   supported for detached entities or entities that are loaded with
>   'AsNoTracking()'.'. This exception can be suppressed or logged by
>   passing event ID 'CoreEventId.DetachedLazyLoadingWarning' to the
>   'ConfigureWarnings' method in 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' or
>   'AddDbContext'.

I don't use AsNoTracking() anywhere in my code.

The DbQuery is defined in `OnModelCreating` of the context. Excerpt:

```
 modelBuilder.Query<ProjectView>()
                .ToQuery(() => Projects
                .Select(p => new ProjectView()
                {
                    Id = p.Id,
                    ProjectCategory = p.ProjectCategory,
                    ProjectPhase = p.ProjectStatus.ProjectPhase,
                }));
```

`Projects` is a DbSet of the context.
`Project.ProjectCategory` is a notMapped-Readonly-Property that uses the relation `Project.ProjectStatus`.

The Properties of the context:

```
public virtual DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<ProjectStatus> ProjectStatus { get; set; }
public virtual DbQuery<ProjectView> ProjectViews { get; set; }
```

Excerpt of the classes:

```
    public partial class Project
    {
            [NotMapped]
            public string ProjectCategory
            {
                get
                {
                    if (this.ProjectStatus == null)
                        return string.Empty;
                    var foo = "someweiredcalculations";

                    return foo
                }
            }
            public virtual ProjectStatus ProjectStatus { get; set; }
            public int ProjectStatusId { get; set; }
            public int Id { get; set; }

}

public class ProjectView
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ProjectCategory { get; set; }
        public string ProjectPhase { get; set; }
}

public partial class ProjectStatus : BaseEntity, IIdEntity<int>
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ProjectPhase { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; } = new HashSet<Project>();

    }
```

How can I make Lazy Loading work for this DbQuery?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a bug of sorts (haven't found work around and [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10042) is still open). Also read [this](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13173#issuecomment-417705155). As advised and I’m quoting

> Note that the warning can be configured to not throw using ConfigureWarnings in the DbContextOptionsBuilder.

Comment: As I wrote, I **don't** use `AsNoTracking()`. When configuring `options.ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Default(WarningBehavior.Ignore));` the error does still occur.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be by design, regardless whether .AsNoTracking() is used or not. I did not find any documentation on this.

If you are stuck on .net core 2 the only workaround I found was to load related entities in a separate query. Effectively breaking lazy loading.

As of .net core 3+ it is possible to work around this by eager loading related properties (.Include(x => x.ProjectStatus)) when Lazy Loading is Used. This was fixed by: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12780. And the error message when using lazy loading was changed to: 'Unable to track an instance of type 'FooQuery' because it does not have a primary key. Only entity types with primary keys may be tracked.'